# Izpack simple installation just to copy files

Tags: izpack

I am trying to make a very simplistic installer using IzPack. It should do the following two things
1. Copy and paste all the content of dist directory to UserHome/MyApp dir.
2. Execute a batch file to edit registry entry to start the jar file on user logon.

But I am stuck at the first step only! nothing is installed if I use the following XML and generate the installer. Generated installer runs and does show the InstallPanel but nothing is copied to the user_home directory.

From what it seems like I am not able to assign value to Install_path variable.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
    <installation version="1.0">
        <variables>
            <variable name="INSTALL_PATH" value="$USER_HOME/MyApp"/>
        </variables>
        <info>
            <appname>My App</appname>
            <appversion>1.0</appversion>
            <authors>
                <author name="My APP Author" email="support@myapp.com"/>
            </authors>
            <url>http://SomeURL.net</url>
        </info>
          <guiprefs width="640" height="480" resizable="yes"/>
        <locale>
            <langpack iso3="eng"/>
        </locale>
        <panels>
            <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
        </panels>
        <packs>
            <pack name="Base" required="yes">
                <description>The base files</description>
                <fileset dir="dist" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
            </pack>
        </packs>
    </installation>
```

**UPDATE**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<installation version="1.0">
    <variables>
        <variable name="TargetPanel.dir.windows" value="$USER_HOME\MyTeamNinja"/>
        <variable name="TargetPanel.dir.mac" value="$USER_HOME/MyTeamNinja"/>
    </variables>
    <info>
        <appname>My App</appname>
        <appversion>1.0</appversion>
        <authors>
            <author name="MyTeamNinja" email="support@MyTeamNinja.com"/>
        </authors>
        <url>http://myteam.ninja</url>
    </info>
      <guiprefs width="640" height="480" resizable="yes"/>
    <locale>
        <langpack iso3="eng"/>
    </locale>
    <panels>
        <panel classname="DefaultTargetPanel"/>
        <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
        <panel classname="SimpleFinishPanel"/>
    </panels>
    <packs>
        <pack name="Base" required="yes">
            <description>The base files</description>
            <fileset dir="dist" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
        </pack>
    </packs>
</installation>
```

Now as soon as I click the installer it starts the install but in `c:\program files\My App\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is a `TargetPanel`. it allows the user to select the destination dir. to install the files. the location selected in this panel sets the value of `$INSTALL_PATH`.

however, you may also override the default value of the `$INSTALL_PATH`.in order to override the *default* value of `$INSTALL_PATH`, you may do the following:

```
<variables>
  <variable name="TargetPanel.dir.windows" value="$USER_HOME/MyApp"/>
  <variable name="TargetPanel.dir.unix" value="$USER_HOME/MyApp"/>
</variables>
```

or,

```
<variables>
  <variable name="DEFAULT_INSTALL_PATH" value="$USER_HOME/MyApp"/>
</variables>
```

and also, remember to include the ***`TargetPanel` before the `InstallPanel`*** in case you choose to allow the user to select the *target loc.* for the installation.

```
    <panels>
        <panel classname="TargetPanel"/>
        <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
    </panels>
```

See [HERE](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Setting+Default+Installation+Directories) for more on this.

---

**UPDATE:**

- place the entry for `TargetPanel` **before** the `InstallPanel` in the `<panels>` section.
- **remove** the `<resources>` section:
  `<resources>
    <res id="TargetPanel.dir.windows" src="$USER_HOME/MyApp"/>
    <res id="TargetPanel.dir.unix" src="$USER_HOME/MyApp"/>
  </resources>` This is where the error is being generated. Instead use `<variables>` to specify default values for `${INSTALL_PATH}` (see in my answer above).
- also, to set a value for `${INSTALL_PATH}` through `<variables>` you need to use `name="DEFAULT_INSTALL_PATH"` or `TargetPanel.dir.windows/unix`

---

**UPDATE 2:**  The following piece of code installs in the correct location (as specified by you in the `defaultInstallDir.txt`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<installation version="1.0">
    <!-- variables>
        <variable name="TargetPanel.dir.windows" value="$USER_HOME\MyTeamNinja"/>
        <variable name="TargetPanel.dir.mac" value="$USER_HOME/MyTeamNinja"/>
    </variables -->

    <!-- remove the above <varible> section and include the REQUIRED defaultInstallDir.txt to set the value for the DefaultTargetPanel -->
    <resources>
        <res id="TargetPanel.dir" src="defaultInstallDir.txt"/>
    </resources>

    <info>
        <appname>My App</appname>
        <appversion>1.0</appversion>
        <authors>
            <author name="MyTeamNinja" email="support@MyTeamNinja.com"/>
        </authors>
        <url>http://myteam.ninja</url>
    </info>
      <guiprefs width="640" height="480" resizable="yes"/>
    <locale>
        <langpack iso3="eng"/>
    </locale>
    <panels>
        <panel classname="DefaultTargetPanel"/>
        <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
        <panel classname="SimpleFinishPanel"/>
    </panels>
    <packs>
        <pack name="Base" required="yes">
            <description>The base files</description>
            <fileset dir="dist" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
        </pack>
    </packs>
</installation>
```

now, create a file named `defaultInstallDir.txt` and simply write the following within this file :

```
$USER_HOME/MyApp
```

just make sure that you include this file correctly in the installer through the `src=".."` attribute of the `<resources>` section and you're good to go.
***double clicking on the installer directly installs the files in `$USER_HOME/MyApp`*** (in my case: at `C:\Users\Sunny\MyApp`)

Comment: I get `-> Fatal error :
   mtninstall.xml:32: Resource not found: .\$USER_HOME\MyApp
com.izforge.izpack.compiler.CompilerException: mtninstall.xml:32: Resource not found: .\$USER_HOME\M
yApp` Am I missing something

Comment: 1>`Resource not found: .\$USER_HOME\M yApp` .. there's a space between `M` and `yApp`.

Comment: No there isn't unfortunately my cmd prompt added a new line because of limited width of the window. WHich became a space here. Please see my latest install.xml in the update

Comment: Now my target panel actually shows value "$USER_HOME/MyApp" $USER_HOME is not being expanded

Comment: Also, isn't there a way to not show the target panel at all and just install the files in user dir?

Comment: `TargetPanel` is specifically to allow users to choose the dest dir. but, there is the `DefaultTargetPanel` to force using a specific dest. dir. See its usage http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/06/12/izpack-changing-location-of-installation/

Comment: also, did you get past the `$USER_HOME` issue? somehow i'm not able to replicate it on my system. for me, its getting expanded properly

Comment: and, keep this: `<variables><variable name="TargetPanel.dir.windows" value="$USER_HOME/MyApp"/></variables>` ... remove the other two variable declarations. you are trying to refer to the **same variable** in three ways. Check for order of precedence here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Setting+Default+Installation+Directories

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked, now how can I get rid of the TargetPanel. This way as soon as I click on the installer the app gets installed in the USER_HOME

Comment: try replacing `<panel classname="TargetPanel"/>` with `<panel classname="DefaultTargetPanel"/>` and see if it works. and also, pls update the **`UPDATE`** section of you ques. with your latest code.

Comment: Kind of worked but now it installs everything in program files. So the settings we made did not effect the actual install

Comment: oh. then **remove both `<variable>`** entries and implement this link: http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/06/12/izpack-changing-location-of-installation/

Comment: Hey, I know this is almost extortion but may I ask you one last question? As of now I have to use SimlpeFinishPanel but is there a way to put finish button right on the InstallPanel.